# Do all slicers handle multi object .STL files correctly for multi color printing?

Tags: slicing, stl, prusaslicer

I only have experience with PrusaSlicer, where if I have one .STL file containing multiple volumes, I can click a `Split to parts` button to then be able to change color of the individual volumes.

Do other slicer softwares handle this similarly or will I face a problem in other softwares?

I'm looking to upload my files for other people to print, and I would prefer to have 1 file per print. Can I upload these .STL files containing multiple volumes or should I rather upload separate .STLs?

Edit: I was mainly looking for typical hobbyist slicers. I was looking to upload the files to a typical online 3d print sharing service for hobbyists.

Comment: While there are only a handful common slicers, there are several hundred slicers in existence (some of them proprietary for specific industrial printers!) and technically every maker is its own slicer if they write the G-code manually. please add constraints.

Comment: That's a good point. Certainly there are slicers out there that don't even support .STLs at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting up the files into separate objects should preferably be done outside a slicer, there are tools for that. Meshmixer, Blender, any CAD program that imports STL files, etc. will do that. You could upload a single file and let others worry about breaking them apart their selves if their slicer of choice doesn't accept a single file for multi colored printings.